# The forbidden error occurs, when I try to link an account to another user with an email

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a user's refresh token with these scopes:

> 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users’’](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users%E2%80%99%E2%80%99)

The user has a few accounts and a forbidden error occurs for XXXX2 account when I try to give access to an account to another user(you can see at the below code and account list json). I checked this account's effective permission field, I see that it is an empty array as you can see below as well.

In my opinion, this error reason is that this user does not have ‘manage_users’ permissions for this account(XXXX2), so this is an expected error, isn't it?

PS: I can link XXXX1 properly with the below code.

My code :

```
linkAccount = self.service.management().accountUserLinks().insert(
        accountId=accountId,
        body={
            'permissions': {
                'local': [
                    'EDIT',
                    'MANAGE_USERS'
                    ]
            },
            'userRef': {
                'email': email}}).execute()
```

User Account list :

```
{
        "id": "XXXX1",
        "kind": "analytics#account",
        "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/XXXX1”,
        "name": "XXXX1",
        "permissions": {
            "effective": [
                "COLLABORATE",
                "EDIT",
                "MANAGE_USERS",
                "READ_AND_ANALYZE"
            ]
        },
        "created": "2014-02-17T17:52:10.911Z",
        "updated": "2019-06-04T16:06:12.717Z",
        "childLink": {
            "type": "analytics#webproperties",
            "href": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/XXXX1/webproperties"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "XXXX2”,
        "kind": "analytics#account",
        "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/XXXX2”,
        "name": "XXXX2",
        "permissions": {
            "effective": []
        },
        "created": "2015-07-02T19:11:16.307Z",
        "updated": "2019-03-05T21:16:19.552Z",
        "childLink": {
            "type": "analytics#webproperties",
            "href": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/XXXX2/webproperties"
        }
    }
```

Error Code :

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://analytics.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/XXXXX/entityUserLinks?alt=json returned "User does not have permission to perform this operation.". Details: "User does not have permission to perform this operation."
```

Comment: Have you checked in Google Analytics if the user have MANAGE_USERS permission?

Comment: please edit your question and include the full error message

Comment: Thank you for quick response.
I added the error code. As I mentioned the user has access to a few analytic accounts. The API can not add another user for the analytics account which permission is like as '"permissions": {"effective": []},'! Does it mean the authenticated user has only read-only access for this account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check what access the currently authenticated user has to the account in question.

If the user you are authenticated with only has read access. To the Analytica account there not going to be able to give your application the ability to add another user.